# Redimensionamento automático de div conforme largura da janela

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, css3

<sup>Minha duvida pode ser um pouco besta e com certeza muitos vão me achar meio burro, apesar de já ter algumas experiencias com front e end.</sup>

A duvida e a seguinte, eu quero fazer um site que se estenda a toda a tela independente da largura, preciso que do lado esquerdo onde ficaria meu `menu` tenha um **tamanho fixo** e meu `div` do lado direito **comece apos este e estenda** até o final da largura da janela, usando `WIDTH:100%` não funciona como eu quero.

Como posso fazer isso de maneira que não use **frameworks**, estou sem o código no momento.

Agradeço se puderem me dar dicas, estou pensando em tentar usar **jQuery** para mudar uma classe no css do div direito usando um calculo com o tamanho total da janela ao carregar.

Comment: Pesquise e estude sobre CSS _flexbox_.

Comment: Sua pergunta está rasa, existem várias formas de fazer isso, sem seu código não da para dizer o que seria bom para o seu caso. pode ser flex, grid, calc, position fixede absolute ou,float. Vc precisa incluir o que tem de código já

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Você pode resolver esse problema com flexbox

um bom site para estudar flexbox na prática é [esse aqui](https://codepen.io/enxaneta/full/adLPwv) você consegue ver na pratica o efeito de cara propriedade

```css
.wrapper{
  height: 100vh;
  display:flex;
}

.menu{
  height: 100%;
  width: 200px;
  background-color:red;
}
.conteudo{
  height:100%;
  flex:1;
  /* você pode usar width:100%, mas isso vai fazer com que o .menu
  fique menor e você iria precisar colocar um min-width:200px nele*/
  background-color:blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">

  <div class="menu"></div>
  <div class="conteudo"></div>

</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Boa tarde, se bem entendi você pode fazer assim:

```
<html>
<head>
    <style>
        .conteiner {
            width: 100% !important;
            height: 100% !important;
            border: 1px solid red;
            display: inline-flex;
        }
        .menu-left {
            width: 120px;
            height: 100%;
            position: relative;
            border: 1px solid blue;
        }
        .page {
            width: 100%;
            height: 100%;
            position: relative;
            border: 1px solid green;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="conteiner">
        <div class="menu-left">MENU</div>
        <div class="page">PÁGINA</div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Note que defini um contêiner com altura e largura máxima do `viewport` e que setei a propriedade `display: inline-flex;`. Recomendo fortemente você começar a usar Framework de front-end e back-end para seus projetos.

Comment: framework de front-end nao é muito necessario, na verdade nem recomendo, faz com que seu site perca a originalidade, mas de back sim